# Calling web api controller through MVC controller / ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

what is the difference for below web api calls.

1. Make a web api call through MVC controller to get the data from database.

> ClientScript -> MVC controller method -> Web Api controller.

It returns data respectively and will be render in page.

2. Make a web api call through Ajax.request to get the data from database.

> ClientScript -> Web Api controller

It returns data and will be render in page.

Thanks.

Comment: First *Make a web api call through MVC controller to get the data from database* **Why you think to do it.? of course it's not good to use WebApi as DAL.**

Comment: If the web api is part of your site, why making an extra call ? Just call from client side js

Comment: In my current organization, people used to consume web api like that only.

Comment: 2 calls vs 1 call. It is your call!

Comment: Actually ,API will not directly communicate with database. There is another layer to communicate with the database. WEB API -> DAL library. @Div

Comment: *In my current organization, people used to consume web api like that only* It seems like superstitions.

Comment: I just eager to know what is the difference between these two approaches.